# Menu behaviour in PySimpleGUI and PySimpleGUIQt

Tags: pysimplegui

I'm a novice PySimpleGUI user, but I'm liking it a great deal. The simple GUIs I've developed so far work well with both PySimpleGUI and PySimpleGUIQt. But today I stubbed my toe at something that's not seamlessly convertible. It's a very simple menu:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
...
    sg.theme('LightGreen5')
    menu_def = [['&File', ['&Open', 'C&lose'],]]

    layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, background_color=('white'), text_color=('black'), \
              font=('Arial'))], \ ...
```

This doesn't work with PySimpleGUIQt. It complains about the `background_color` and `text colours`, as well as about the `font` options. But if I remove those options, leaving only

```
    layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def)], \ ...
```

it does work, but produces a quite cheesy, tasteless menu.

I much prefer Qt to tkinter (or whatever it is used when PySimpleGUIQt is not imported and used) but don't know what to do to use Qt *and* have the nice menu produced by tkinter (or whatever, etc). Do I have to create two distinct versions, one for Qt and another one to [whatever]? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PySimpleGUIQt is just a User Alpha, so there's no options `text_color` and `font` in `sg.Menu`.

Here's workaround to provide color and font to `sg.Menu`.

```py
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

def menu_options(menu):

    style = """
        QMenuBar {
            background-color : white;
        }
        QMenuBar::item {
            spacing: 0px;
            padding: 2px 10px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
        QMenuBar::item:selected {
            color: white;
            background-color: red;
        }
        QMenuBar::item:pressed {
            color: white;
            background: blue;
        }
        QMenu {
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 2px;
        }
        QMenu::item {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        QMenu::item:selected {
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
        }
    """

    menu = menu.Widget
    menu.setStyleSheet(style)

    font = sg.QFont('Courier New', 16, sg.QFont.Bold, True) # Family, size, bold, italic
    font.setUnderline(True)
    font.setStrikeOut(True)
    menu.setFont(font)
    for submenu in menu.findChildren(sg.QMenu):
        submenu.setFont(font)

sg.theme('LightGreen5')
menu_def = [
    ['&File', ['&Open', 'C&lose'],],
    ['&Edit', ['&Copy', '&Paste'],],
]
layout = [
    [sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENU-')],
    [sg.Text("Hello World", font=('Arial', 24))],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
menu_options(window['-MENU-'])

window.read()
window.close()
```

[image]